# Angular Extracting input from a table selected row

Tags: angular

I have a table that contains editable column, I just need to be able to extract the value from the selected row. How Can I get the input value (comment) field

component.html

```
     <tr *ngFor="let bsa of bsaFollowup| orderBy: key : reverse ; let i = index" (click)="GetfollowupID(bsa.ID)">
                                <td style="width:18%">{{bsa.AccessFor}}</td>

                               <td style="width:32%"><div *ngIf="i !== editRowIndex">{{bsa.Comments}}</div> <div >
<input type="text"  *ngIf="i === editRowIndex" id="comment" name="comment" [(ngModel)]="bsa.Comments"  /></div></td>
                                <td style="width:15%">

                                    <modal [rowIndex]="i" (open)="onOpen($event)"  (edit)="onEdit($event)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit($event)"></modal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
    </tr>
```

Component.ts

```
onEdit(index: number) {
        this.editRowIndex = index;
        console.log('on edit comment: ');


    }
```

modal.component

```
 @Input() rowIndex: number = -1
    @Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() edit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() cancelEdit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    showModal: boolean = true;
    onEdit() {

        this.edit.emit(this.rowIndex);
        this.showModal = false;
    }
```

screenshot
[image]

*****************************************************update*********************************************
component html

```
<input type="text" #myInput (change)="myChange($event,i)" *ngIf="i === editRowIndex" id="comment" name="comment" [(ngModel)]="bsa.Comments"  />
```

event.target.value does return the newly entered/modified comment, however, this.selectedNewBsaComment is returning null
component.ts

```
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {  

 selectedNewBsaComment: any;
ChangeComments: any;

 ngOnInit(): void {
//some code
      }

onEdit(index: number) {
        this.editRowIndex = index;
        this.selectedNewBsaComment = this.bsaFollowup[index].Comments;
        console.log('selectedNewBsaComment ' + this.selectedNewBsaComment);      


    }
    myChange(event, index) {
        var comments = this.bsaFollowup[index].Comments;
        console.log('new comment ' + event.currentTarget.value);
        this.ChangeComments = event.currentTarget.value;
        console.log('new ChangeComments ' +  this.ChangeComments);
    }

}
```

output:
correctly displaying the new comments

> console.log('new comment ' + event.currentTarget.value);
>   console.log('new ChangeComments ' +  this.ChangeComments);

always display the original comment

> console.log('selectedNewBsaComment ' + this.selectedNewBsaComment);

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Can you show us the problem? or console log for example

Comment: so sorry left out the most important detail :) . I edited my above post..I need to be able to get the input comment from the selected row..see above code

Comment: The input value is given by `bsa.Comments`. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, bsa.comment is used to pre-populate the existing comment in the text box..see screenshot above..i am looking to use the id or the name of the input box to get the new/modified comment from user

Comment: when you used onEdit($event) try to handle the event in the function `onEdit($event)` like this: `$event.target.value` it's not recommended but it is worth to give a try.

Comment: it did not work onEdit(index: number) {
        this.editRowIndex = index;
        console.log('on edit comment: ' + $event.target.value);

       
    }

Comment: $event.target.value does not exists

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a change for input box and pass the index as a argument

```
(change)="myChange($event,i)"
```

And then in the change event get the current value of comments using the index recieved

```
myChange(event,index){
var comments=this.bsaFollowup[index].Comments;
}
```

Comment: Updated my code...this will give me the original comment not the modified version

Comment: Ok can you check the event.args.value or any proprrty in event parameter of the change function

Comment: when i tried to d this:     myChange(event, index) {
        var comments = this.bsaFollowup[index].Comments;
        console.log('new comment ' + event.target.value);
    }  Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: your html code for change event is  `(change)="myChange(event,i)" `which should be
`(change)="myChange($event,i)"`
$event is the current event which is triggered

Comment: I updated my code..see above code...getting error 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: Did u try event.target.value r just check the event object in change method to see where value is set

Comment: event.target.value does return the newly entered/modified comment, however, this.selectedNewBsaComment is returning null. I have to have the value onEdit becuase this is an even called when a user click on the save button to confirm they want to save the new comment

Answer (score 0):

I have added a online editor for your reference. 
[Editor Reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtxrvr)

you have to use `event.currentTarget.value` in the change event to get the value

Comment: Thanks Darsandsk22, this is drving me crazy I spent more than two hours comparing the reference you added with my code. I still have he same issue onEdit evnt displays the original comment...(I updated my code..see above code) The only difference i see is i am my component implements onInt

Comment: Just check if you have added the proper modules like browsermodule and formsmodule